# Role base Json output in Spring Boot

Tags: json, spring-mvc, spring-boot, jackson

Is is possible to exclude `JsonProperties` in the output of a Spring Boot Rest call based on a defined condition? (eg. the role of the user)

Example:

```
public class Employee{

    @JsonProperty
    private String name;
    @JsonProperty
    private String fieldForManagerOnly;
    @JsonProperty
    private String fieldForEmployeeOnly;

}
```

I want to have the `fieldForManagerOnly` only serialized in the JSON output when the user has the ROLE `manager`.

I've already tried the solution with the `@JsonView` (as described in [Latest Jackson integration improvements in Spring](https://spring.io/blog/2014/12/02/latest-jackson-integration-improvements-in-spring)) but that solution is very limited as the `@JsonView` is bound to one controler method and I want to have only one controller method.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've solved the problem myself. I used the JsonView solution but instead of an annotation I select the JsonView from code.

First you need an interface for the Views.

```
public class JsonViews {

    public  interface EmployeeView {}
    public  interface ManagerView {}

}
```

Mark the fields in the Model class with the @JsonView annotations.

```
public class Employee{

    @JsonProperty
    private String name;

    @JsonView(JsonViews.ManagerView.class)
    private String fieldForManagerOnly;

    @JsonView(JsonViews.EmployeeView.class)
    private String fieldForEmployeeOnly;

}
```

In your controller set the JsonView to use based on the role (or some other condition):

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{employeeId}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<MappingJacksonValue> getEmployee(@PathVariable long employeeId) {
    Employee employee = employeeService.getEmployee(employeeId);
    MappingJacksonValue jacksonValue = new MappingJacksonValue(employeeResourceAssembler.toResource(employee));

    if (getRole().equals("MANAGER")) {
        jacksonValue.setSerializationView(JsonViews.ManagerView.class);
    } else if (getRole().equals("EMPLOYEE")) {
        jacksonValue.setSerializationView(JsonViews.EmployeeView.class);
    }

    return new ResponseEntity<>(jacksonValue, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Comment: That's a nice solution that I didn't know about. You got my upvote.

Comment: Similar to my workaround here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29838960/how-to-dynamically-remove-fields-from-a-json-response/30133798#30133798

Answer (score 0):

Annotate the field with

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
```

and make sure to set the field `fieldForManagerOnly` to `null` if the current user is not a manager.

Comment: Do we have a better way to implement it using spring boot?